# Can I use a more advanced camera in Unity for AR application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new to Unity3d, and I've asked this question on their forums but NO response.
I know I can use a 'webcam' (did this using RawImage, etc.) to make an AR application, but I need to be able to use a more advanced (microscope) camera.

The camera I'm using now in my C# VS program is a Toupcam similar to this:
http://www.touptek.com/product/showproduct.php?lang=en&id=195

It has its own SDK and DLLs that work well in windows 10, etc.

I've searched posts here as well and see many good solutions for webcams, but nothing for more advanced cameras.

Before I sink 100s of hours in Unity developing my HUD, I need to know if I can use this or similar advanced camera.

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm just getting into Unity. Love it so far, but can't figure this out. I can 'see' my Logitech webcam, but not the Toupcam.

THANKS.

Comment: What is the AR SDK you are using? In Vuforia, if your camera is usable, it will show in the list of webcam camera. You mention you can't see it, it could be that the SDK does not support the resolution.

Comment: I'm not using an AR SDK, Just regular Unity 5.5.  
In my stand alone C# program I access the camera through it's own SDK, e.g. 
`include toupcam` . I've looked a bit at Vuforia but can't afford its pricing structure. Also I don't think it 'supports' the more advanced cameras, but I may be wrong.

Comment: if the toupcam sdk is compatible with .net 3.5, then you can use the sdk within unity (its just a bit hacky to set up (at least in my opinion)). See this doc page https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html